XHRGET https://google-analytics-getIT!!!-projects.vercel.app/data
Trying to display GA4 results with help of a serverless vercel node.js "project". After running node index.js, cannot authenticate in browser like "http://localhost:3000/auth" (it shows in terminal "No Tokens Available"). Before i could, am also changing the "Authorized redirect URIs" everytime i hit "vercel" in terminal to deploy, with no results.
In GoogleCloud API and Services got this:
Authorized JavaScript origins: "http://localhost:3000"
Authorized redirect URIs:
URIs 1 "http://localhost:3000/auth/callback"
URIs 2  "https://google-analytics-whateverHashAppears-projects.vercel.app/auth/callback"
     app.get('/auth', (req, res) => {
          const authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
              access_type: 'offline',
              scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
          });
          res.redirect(authUrl);
      });
      
      app.get('/auth/callback', async (req, res) => {
          const { code } = req.query;
          try {
              const { tokens: authTokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken(code);
              oauth2Client.setCredentials(authTokens);
              tokens = authTokens;
              console.log('Tokens:', tokens);
              res.send('Authentication successful! You can now close this tab.');
          } catch (error) {
              console.error('Error during authentication:', error);
              res.status(500).send('Authentication failed');
          }
      });
    
    
     app.get('/data', async (req, res) => {
          if (!tokens) {
              console.log('No tokens available');
              return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');
          }
     try {
              const response = await analyticsData.properties.runReport({
                  property: 'properties/ga4NumberIsCorrect', // Replace with your GA4 Property ID
                  requestBody: {
                      dateRanges: [
                          {
                              startDate: '30daysAgo',
                              endDate: 'today',
                          },
                      ],
                      metrics: [{ name: 'activeUsers' }],
                      dimensions: [{ name: 'date' }],
                  },
              });
      
              console.log('Google Analytics response:', response.data);
              res.json(response.data);
          } catch (error) {
              console.error('Error fetching data:', error.response ? error.response.data : error);
              res.status(500).send('Error fetching data');
          }

    ```

